# How to save Google chrome state?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I want to know if there is a way to save Google chrome state in order to open it from other PC using my Google account, i just want to save the tabs opened now to open them from other PC without any problems, i tried to Google it but all i found is the way to save the tabs to open it from the same PC, the following picture for demonstration: 
[image: example]

Also i want to know if i can do that using my gmail on another browser like Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

This chrome plugin might do what you are looking for:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcloud/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon